# API assertion failure message to be displayed in my testNG report

Tags: testng, reporting, assertions, rest-assured

I am having multiple assertions (assertTrue) in my test method, I want to pass the assertion failure to my @AfterMethod on which ever assertion my test failed so that I can get the exact location where my API test failed. Is there any way to achieve this?
Using Rest assured, Maven & TestNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `@AfterMethod` can accept a `ITestResult` as a parameter, which TestNG during execution natively injects the test result of the last `@Test`. So you can examine the `ITestResult` object and then proceed further.

Here's a simple sample

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class SampleTestClass {

    @Test
    public void passMethod() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void failMethod() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult testResult) {
        if (testResult.isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }
        Throwable throwable = testResult.getThrowable();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sw);
        throwable.printStackTrace(writer);
        System.err.println("****" + sw.getBuffer().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Used soft asserts to achieve what i wanted. assertAll() containing a map to store all failed asserts. Thanks for replying.